# Using Expressions with Xpath

Tags: xpath

[image]

My problem is to find the titles and each of the last name of the first author of all articles.I have an assignment on xpath and this is the last question i've been banging my head for over an hour but i can't figure it out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Tips for general SO usage. Post the image/HTML/XML/Whatever here incase in the future the website you are linking to goes down (And then your question loses all context), and post some things you have tried so we can correct where you went wrong (Better than us just answering homework assignments all day!)

Comment: If you've been trying for an hour what have you tried? Can you show us where your issue is?

Comment: It's very hard to work with XML that you show the structure of in an image. When you [edit] your question to post the actual effort you've made to solve this problem, please also include a small, relevant sample of XML (**not** a list of 5000 publications, but a **small, relevant sample**). It's impossible to copy/paste from a graphic to test or debug anything, and I'm certainly not going to write a sample of XML to match your description in order to try and help. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is find all of the articles. Now we can either do this knowing their specific position in the tree - `/Publications/Proceedings/Article` - or find all the Articles, wherever they are - `//Article`. However, this gives us too much infromation and needs to be narrowed down.

What we need is **two pieces of information**, the title of the article and the last name of the first Author.

Getting the title, is easier as from the Article, we can just grab the title, like so: `Article/Title`.

To get the Author information is slightly harder, the lastname of anygiven Author can be done like: `Author/Surname`, however we need one one Author.

To get the first Author of any given article, we can just use the `position()` function to grab the first one ( remembering that XML array indexing starts at 1): `Author[position()=1]`. We can shortcut this by just using the number itself - `Author[1]`

From here you have enough information to build the *two* XPaths you need. Good luck.